# Jquery calculator base price + 25%

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I have a Jquery Calculator.

My select options have data in for price
this is the base price.

Then I have checkboxes, which need to add 25% on to the base price

```
<select  name="howlongcover" class="servicevalue1 howlongcover1"  id="servicevalue1">
    <option  value="none" data-price="0">Pick one!</option>
    <option data-price="55" value="valuhowlongcover" data-capacity="24 Months" >24 Months</option>
    <option value="valuhowlongcover" data-price="58" data-capacity="36 Months">36 Months</option>
    <option value="valuhowlongcover" data-price="71" data-capacity="48 Months" >48 Months</option>
    <option  value="valuhowlongcover" data-price="119"  data-capacity="60 Months">60 Months</option> 
</select>



<label><input class="calculate" id="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="checks" data-price="25"> <span></span> option 1</label><BR>
<label><input class="calculate" id="checkboxes1"  type="checkbox" name="checks" data-price="25"> <span></span>option 2</label><BR>
<label><input class="calculate" id="checkboxes2" type="checkbox" name="checks" data-price="25"> <span></span>Option 3</label><BR>
```

Here is my Jquery

```
 $(function(){

    $("select.valuservicevalue1").on("change", calc);
    $("select.valuservicevalue2").on("change", calc);
    $("select.valuservicevalue3").on("change", calc);
    $("select.valuservicevalue4").on("change", calc);
    $("select.valuservicevalue5").on("change", calc);
    $("input[type=checkbox].calculate").on("click", calc);

  function calc() {
   var basePrice = 0;
    newPrice = basePrice;

    $("select.valuservicevalue1 option:selected, select.valuservicevalue2 option:selected, select.valuservicevalue3 option:selected, select.valuservicevalue4 option:selected, select.valuservicevalue5 option:selected").each(function () {
      newPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
    });

    $("input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function () {
      var price = $("#item-price").html();
      newPrice += price * .25;
    });

    newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
    $("#item-price").html(newPrice);
  }
});
```

Right now it will take select down option price for example
55.00
If a checkbox is ticked it will then add 25% to 55.00 = 68.75 (works great!)
However if another checkbox is ticked then it add's 25% on to 68.75, where as it should add the 50% (because 2 checkboxes are ticked) to 55.00

I have 3 checkboxes in total all to add 25% to the select option price,

I have also just noticed if I removed a checkbox it does not seem to amend the calculator properly
55 + 1 check box = 68.75 + another checkbox = 89.38 untick a checkbox = 77.34

How can I go about fixing this? Can anyone help please

Comment: I can remember I answered this question before .. go back to my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56571856/3385827

Comment: How about adding a variable NumberOfCheckedBoxes that stores the number of checked checkboxes and use that to calculate the % increased? @user1348927

Comment: Also, you can add a class like "changeCalc" to all the select.Valueservice... doms and just call $(".changeCalc").on("change",calc) this will reduce the code :)

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is:** You get price from `var price = $("#item-price").html();` then you get `price * .25` `25%` of the total price not from `55`

- Also with checkbox use `change` event instead of `click`
- You can combine selectors `$("#selector1 , #selector2 , ....").on('change' , calc)`

You can use this function

```js
$(function(){
    $("select#servicevalue1 , input[type=checkbox].calculate").on("change", calc);

  function calc() {
   var basePrice = 0;
    newPrice = basePrice;

    $("select.servicevalue1 option:selected").each(function () {
      newPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
    });
    var percentage = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function(){
        percentage += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
    });
    newPrice = newPrice + (newPrice * percentage / 100 );
    newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
    $("#item-price").html(newPrice);
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  name="howlongcover" class="servicevalue1 howlongcover1"  id="servicevalue1">
    <option  value="none" data-price="0">Pick one!</option>
    <option data-price="55" value="valuhowlongcover" data-capacity="24 Months" >24 Months</option>
    <option value="valuhowlongcover" data-price="58" data-capacity="36 Months">36 Months</option>
    <option value="valuhowlongcover" data-price="71" data-capacity="48 Months" >48 Months</option>
    <option  value="valuhowlongcover" data-price="119"  data-capacity="60 Months">60 Months</option> 
</select>



<label><input class="calculate" id="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="checks" data-price="25"> <span></span> option 1</label><BR>
<label><input class="calculate" id="checkboxes1"  type="checkbox" name="checks" data-price="25"> <span></span>option 2</label><BR>
<label><input class="calculate" id="checkboxes2" type="checkbox" name="checks" data-price="25"> <span></span>Option 3</label><BR>

<div id="item-price">0.00</div>
```